# Using existing widget code!

Tags: php, themes, widgets

Maybe this was answered many times but I couldn't find my answers so here I go:
Am I allowed to use widgets php code from other existing themes and modify it for my needs?

Comment: In substance, it depends on licence, if theme license allow you are allowed. However, this has nothing to do with WordPress, so I voted to close as off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the license of theme you're intending to make a derivative work of.

You'll find a related debate on wordpress.org here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-licensing

...and another individuals cumulative research on the matter here: http://bloggingexperiment.com/is-blogging-experiment-breaking-the-law

Additionally, here's an example of the a web designer legitimately modifying a premium theme on Theme Forest and reselling it as his own (Stack Overflow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024882/can-i-edit-a-wordpress-theme-gpl-licensed-and-then-sell-it